# Globalization Testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

How can I test a product which is available in different cultures like USA, UK, Europe? Is there any library files that are needed to be added? Any ideas would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi John, could you be a bit more specific on what you are trying to test and what you're testing when you say culture? Are you meaning from a technical perspective or actually cultural perspective?

Comment: In Automation Verification script While Verifying price calculations  for Us Culture it comes with Dollar sign and Similarly Pounds for UK  everytime in my code im removing currency symbol Instead of removing Currencies how can i Check with Currency type

Comment: Hi John, it sounds like you are asking how you can verify the amount of money (involved in some transaction or product) if each country has a different currency and those currencies have specific conversions. Correct?

Comment: Absolutely Chris ,do you know how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do **localization testing**, aka test the differences each country or locale brings to your application (such as currency conversions from Dollars to Euros).

In that case **I recommend using a proxy service** (such as [WonderProxy](https://wonderproxy.com/)) to test your application. Proxy services basically make it seem like your traffic originated in whatever locale you set (France, UK, India) so you see all the correct locale conversions such as currency, date, time, etc. This is great because you can get a consistent experience to test your changes without having to "trick" your services to think you are local.

You can use most proxies as VPNs as well, so you can try this in an manual or exploratory way initially but over time automate it (which is sounds like you do since you mentioned a "script") so you can repeatedly check conversions. For example with a service like WonderProxy you can hook their Proxy service into Selenium tests to do a lot of this testing for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has multiple languages to support they probably have po files. If you have access to them you can poll all texts from your AUT via a normal full test and log all occurrences where the levensthein distance from your expected string is above a certain threshold. I'd also log everything where msgid equals msgstr since people often copy paste them to "add it later" and forget about it.